# Detect an error node/element and exit out a loop and not insert in table VB.net

Tags: xml, vb.net

I have a Sub that I've created that returns specific information back to me in XML format. However, sometime when I pass in a value into the Sub, and it returns back with error nodes/elements.I would like to skip these error nodes/elements or break away from it, before it goes into the table. How can this be achieved? Below is my code:

```
returnXML = getXml(ISBN)

'Assuming this is where I'm supposed to write a for each loop before going into the table to detect the error nodes?

dtReturnXMl(returnXML)

Public Sub dtReturnXML(getReturnXML As String)
dsReturn.Read(New XmlTextReader(New StringReader(getReturnXML)))
dvReturn = dsReturn.Tables("Offer").DefaultView
dvReturn.Sort = "Merchant, Condition ASC"
dtReturn = dvRturn.ToTable("Offer")
End Sub
```

XML from returnXML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<Response>
  <Errors>
    <Error>
      <ErrorMessage>One or more ISBNS not found</ErrorMessage>
    </Error>
    <Error>
      <ErrorMessage>One or more ISBNS not found</ErrorMessage>
    </Error>
  </Errors>
</Response>
```

Comment: What does the method return when there is not an error?

Comment: It returns book information, like price, title, isbn etc...

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Imports System.Xml
Imports System.Xml.Linq
Module Module1

    Sub Main()
        Dim returnXML As XDocument = getXml("ISBN")
        Dim errors As String() = returnXML.Descendants("ErrorMessage").Select(Function(x) x.Value).ToArray

    End Sub
    Function getXml(ISBN As String) As XDocument
        Dim xml As String = _
                "<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""UTF-8""?>" & _
                "<Response>" & _
                    "<Errors>" & _
                        "<Error>" & _
                            "<ErrorMessage>One or more ISBNS not found</ErrorMessage>" & _
                        "</Error>" & _
                        "<Error>" & _
                            "<ErrorMessage>One or more ISBNS not found</ErrorMessage>" & _
                        "</Error>" & _
                    "</Errors>" & _
                "</Response>"

        Return XDocument.Parse(xml)

    End Function

End Module
```